# Hide/Show footer on the focus of input elements in IONIC

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic, I am trying to hide menu once the keypad is up on-focus of input element.

```
<ion-input class="inputtext" formControlName="wateratSlump"  (ionFocus)="checkFocus()" type="number" tabindex="1">
</ion-input>
```

In ts file

```
  checkFocus(){
    document.body.classList.add('keyboard-open');
  }
```

Css

```
.keyboard-open{
  ion-footer{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I am able to hide it onfocus but once the focus is gone I want to show this again.
Help me in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ionFocus and ionBlur with hidden in ion-footer like below example

### html

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-input class="inputtext" (ionFocus)="checkFocus()" type="number" tabindex="1" (ionBlur)="checkBlur()">
    </ion-input>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <button class="proceed" [hidden]="isShown" ion-button full (click)="proceedPayment()">Proceed</button>
</ion-footer>
```

### ts

```
export class HomePage {

    isShown = false;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    checkFocus(){
        this.isShown = true;
    }

    checkBlur() {
        this.isShown = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Great Paresh :) Thanks for ur help

Comment: Glad to help you.!